# mobile safari - navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition "chokes" application if bookmarked (fullscreen)

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I discovered this strange behavior with the web application that I am developing using html5's geolocation API. The problem only occurs if the website is bookmarked and then run in the *full screen* mode on the iPad using
        `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`
in the header.

The code I am using:

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    alert("No problem up to here");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, noLocation, { timeout:   10000 });
}
else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
  alert("position: " + position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude);
}

function noLocation(error) {
  alert("error.code:" + error.code);
}
```

And then I am calling getLocation() from another function:

```
    timer = window.setInterval(function () { getLocation() }, 10000);
```

(and yes, I already have declared timer)

I used the word "choke" because I can see "No problem up to here" alert every 10 seconds, the "`position:`" alert just once, and after then neither of the "`position:`" or "`error.code:`" alerts are showing up.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: That is what is supposed to happen when the popup asking for permission comes up and the user clicks either the close window (x) in chrome, or firefox, or the "Not Now" button in safari or simply doesn't answer it and leaves it up.  Did you click "Not now", or perhaps for some reason you aren't seeing the request for your location.

Comment: As far I remember, I clicked "Ok". Now it's not even showing the prompt but I see the little arrow at the right top corner indicating that somehow it remembered my choice and using geolocation.

Comment: try simplifying the alerts, just use a literal like `alert('here');`.  Perhaps the position object isn't coming in the way you expect.

Comment: Already tried that. Actually it's executing the very first time. Then does nothing as I described in the original post. So, I am seeing the "position" alert only once, but "No problem up to here" every 10 seconds.